# Laravel Schema builder drop table on specific connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I created a `users` table using Laravel's schema builder. Here is the migration:

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
                Schema::connection('mysql-internal')->create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
                {
                        $table->increments('id');
                        $table->string('username');
                        $table->string('password');
                        $table->timestamps();
                });
        }

        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
                Schema::connection('mysql-internal')->drop('users');
        }

}
```

After running this migration, I then rolled it back using `php artisan migrate:rollback`. However, it looks like `down` method did not respect my `connection`. The `users` table was dropped from my default mysql database rather than the `mysql-internal` that I specified.

Did I do something wrong here? I am using Laravel 4.2.17.

Comment: Looks like there was an existing past migration with the same class name `CreateUsersTable`. I'm guessing that when I issued the `rollback` command, it found the first instance of that class, and ran its `down()` method, which did not contain the `connection` parameter.